# assignment of bound prefix as variable

Tags: python, rdflib

I'm missing something elementary here I'm sure. Parsing an rdf graph with rdflib gives you a graph object with a `namespaces()` method. This returns a list of tuples with prefixes that are bound to namespace `URIRef`s:

```py
[('xml', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'))
 ('foo', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/scheme#'))
]
```

I want each of those prefixes to be available to my code as variables. I can do this explicitly for each one by doing this:

```py
foo = rdflib.Namespace(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/scheme#'))
```

so that I can do things like this:

```py
g.subject_objects(foo.bar)
```

But is there a pythonic way to take such a list of tuples and for each item, assign the first element string as a variable for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is technically possible using `exec`, I highly recommend taking a different approach such as using a dictionary.

```py
namespaces = dict([
    ('xml', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')),
    ('foo', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/scheme#')),
])

...

g.subject_objects(namespaces['foo'].bar)
```

For the sake of answering the original question, if you absolutely must have dynamic individual variables then you can do something like this:

```py
for variable, value in [('xml', rdflib...), ('foo', rdflib...)]:
    exec(f"{variable} = {value}")

...

g.subject_objects(foo.bar)
```

This is going to create a mess of variables you are unaware of plus possibly override other variables you aren't expecting.

Comment: thanks! I'd forgotten about `exec()` because I so seldom use it, and for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record in this post, in case someone visits in the future: remember that RDFlib comes with a whole bunch of namespaces already loaded:

```py
from rdflib.namespace import BRICK, CSVW, DC, DCAT, DCMITYPE, DCTERMS, DOAP, FOAF, ODRL2, ORG, OWL, PROF, PROV, QB, RDF, RDFS, SDO, SH, SKOS, SOSA, SSN, TIME, VANN, VOID, XMLNS, XSD
```

I tend to declare my own namespaces like this:

```py
from rdflib.namespace import RDFS, XSD
EG = Namespace("http://example.com/")
```

and then just use EG as I would the others, so `<http://example.com/thing>` would be just `EG.thing`.

This doesn't solve the issue asked directly but is useful to know.

Also, no need for:

```py
foo = rdflib.Namespace(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/scheme#'))
```

just this will do:

```py
from rdflib import Namespace
foo = Namespace("http://example.org/scheme#")
```